# Inequality for term of a positive sequence : show $\frac{1}{n} \ge c_n - c_{n+1} \ge \frac{1}{n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}_+^\mathbb{Z}$. Define
\begin{align}
a_n&=\sup_{k \ge n} \{x_k\} \\
b_n&=a_n+\frac{1}{n} \\
c_1&=b_1 \text{ and } c_n=\max\left(c_{n-1}-\frac{1}{n},b_n\right)
\end{align}
Show
$$
\frac{1}{n} \ge c_n - c_{n+1} \ge \frac{1}{n+1}
$$

Writing
\begin{align}
c_n &\ge b_{n+1}, \\
c_n &\ge c_{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}
\end{align}
I get 
$$
c_n-c_{n+1} \le c_n - c_ n+ \frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+1} \le \frac{1}{n}
$$
I don't see how to get the lower bound.

Comment: there is a typo in the definition of c_n

Comment: and also, i guess a_n=sup_{k\geq n}x_k

Comment: @sasposcat Good eyes, thanks.

Comment: A lower bound $1/(n+1)$ is most unlikely since you proved that $1/(n+1)$ is an **upper bound** of $c_n-c_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stated lower bound can fail. Take $x_n=1$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$. Then for $n\in\Bbb N$ we have $a_n=1$ and $b_n=1+\frac1n$. Finally, $c_1=b_1=2$, $$c_2=\max\left\{2-\frac12,1+\frac12\right\}=\frac32\;,$$ and $$c_3=\max\left\{\frac32-\frac13,1+\frac13\right\}=\max\left\{\frac76,\frac43\right\}=\frac43\;,$$ so

$$c_2-c_3=\frac32-\frac43=\frac16<\frac13\;.$$